# Escape quotes in springTemplateEngine

Tags: java, spring, special-characters, template-engine

I have a method which uses springTemplateEngine to generate a non-html text.
My template looks like this:

```
some text
[[${variable}]]
```

but when I run the template engine with `variable` set to a string with quotes:

```
string with "" quotes
```

The quotes are replaced with the html code:

```
some text
string with &quot;&quot; quotes
```

Is there any way to escape this behaviour and have actual quotes appear in the resulting string?

the desired output should be

```
some text
string with "" quotes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your variable syntax, I am assuming, you are using Themeleaf as your TemplateEngine.

You can use `[(${variable})]` syntax to ommit escaping of variable. This was introduced in Themeleaf 3.

See section Escaping on [Themeleaf issue tracker](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/394):

> **Escaping**
>
> These `[[...]]` expressions, as they did in Thymeleaf 2.1, perform an escaping operation on output. So if we have a `title` variable with `String` value `"this & that"`, this:
>
> ```
> <p>Title: [[${title}]]</p>
> ```
>
> will result in:
>
> ```
> <p>Title: this &amp; that</p>
> ```
>
> But what if we need *unescaped* output? We might have a `comment` variable with value `This is a <strong>great</strong> song!` that we know contains HTML (see those `<strong>` tags) that we want to output without being escaped...
>
> In such case we can use an *unescaped output expression*, with syntax `[(...)]` (note the inner parentheses instead of brackets). So:
>
> ```
> <p>Title: [[${title}]]</p>
> <p>Description: [(${description})]</p>
> ```
>
> ...will result in:
>
> ```
> <p>Title: this &amp; that</p>
> <p>Description: This is a <strong>great</strong> song!</p>
> ```
>
> We see therefore how the above is the exact equivalent to:
>
> ```
> <p>Title: <th:block th:text="${title}"/></p>
> <p>Description: <th:block th:utext="${description}"/></p>
> ```